# Facebook like "saves" behavior is inconsistent

Tags: debugging, facebook-like

I created a new app, for a new website, and added "Like" buttons in various relevant places. I run the URL through the debugger, and all looks well, lots of relevant data, no warnings.

I try to "Like", a few URLs, and initially all looks good. However, soon I notice that *some* times, the like does not appear to be saved. Upon reloading the page, the like count goes back to 0, and I need to like again. Sometime it works, sometimes it doesn't.

It's always a great deal of fun debugging inconsistent behavior, so I'm asking the question here, hoping to hear from someone who has experienced similar problems, and figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook APIs are very poorly documented (if at all) and, as you have noticed, behave in unexpected ways.

My only advice is to just not worry about it.  You can waste a huge amount of time trying to understand Facebook APIs.  [I certainly have](http://www.sethcall.com/blog/2010/09/30/facebook-api-does-not-care/).

Comment: A Facebook employee said in that post it was going to get better.  Glad were not holding our breath.

Comment: That's not very encouraging, but I'm glad that you took the time to chime in.